# (python) MNIST with local picture face img AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, typeerror, mnist

environment: google colab, python

goal: python mnist predict my own picture

issue: `AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

**Update tried code, and output**

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
from PIL import Image
(train_images,train_labels),(test_images,test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images.shape
len(train_labels)
train_labels
test_images.shape
len(test_labels)
test_labels


'''plt.imshow(train_images[819], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
print(train_images[819])
print(train_labels[819])'''


from keras import models
from keras import layers
network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512,activation='relu',input_shape=(28*28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))


network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


train_images = train_images.reshape((60000,28*28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32')/255
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000,28*28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')/255

from keras.utils import to_categorical

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

network.fit(train_images,train_labels,epochs=1,batch_size=128)


test_loss , test_acc = network.evaluate(test_images,test_labels)
print('test_acc:',test_acc)



network.save('m_lenet.h5')


#########

import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

model = load_model('/content/m_lenet.h5')

picPath = '/content/00_a.png'
img = Image.open(picPath)


reIm = img.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)

im_arr = np.array(reIm.convert("L"))

im1 = img.reshape((1,28*28))
im1 = img.astype('float32')/255

predict = model.predict_classes(im1)
print ('predict as：')
print (predict)
```

- output: `AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

```
469/469 [==============================] - 6s 11ms/step - loss: 0.2553 - accuracy: 0.9258
313/313 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1399 - accuracy: 0.9582
test_acc: 0.9581999778747559
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-8c95d72a4bf4> in <module>
     68 im_arr = np.array(reIm.convert("L"))
     69 
---> 70 im1 = img.reshape((1,28*28))
     71 im1 = img.astype('float32')/255
     72 

AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

link of the screenshot on google colab, and the pic I want MNIST to predict
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCaY6.jpg

> img name: "00_a.png"
> img path: '/content/00_a.png'

- "ls" result:

```
00_a.png          03_a.png  06_a.png  09_a.png
00_a__result.png  04_a.png  07_a.png  epic_num_reader_joy.model/
02_a.png          05_a.png  08_a.png  m_lenet.h5
02_b.png          05_b.png  09_a.jpg  sample_data/
```

the "00_a.png" is there, and I right click to copy the path is : '/content/00_a.png'

---

with following code, the path "/content/00_a.png" is working

```
import cv2
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

im = cv2.imread("/content/00_a.png",1)  # load image as bgr
im2 = im[:,:,::-1]  # transform image to rgb
plt.imshow(im2)
plt.show()
```

I also share the pic on share link https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCaY6.jpg

that I can use the path to call the picture (ps.`cv2.imshow` will failed , only the `plt.show()` is working in google colab )

---

tried code from export suggestion:

- I'm either input (im_arr) or (reIm) or (img), but they all get some error

> tensor = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(im)

I screenshot 3 result here https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNXmR.jpg

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
from PIL import Image


(train_images,train_labels),(test_images,test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images.shape
len(train_labels)
train_labels
test_images.shape
len(test_labels)
test_labels


'''plt.imshow(train_images[819], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
print(train_images[819])
print(train_labels[819])'''


from keras import models
from keras import layers
network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512,activation='relu',input_shape=(28*28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))


network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


train_images = train_images.reshape((60000,28*28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32')/255
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000,28*28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')/255

from keras.utils import to_categorical

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

network.fit(train_images,train_labels,epochs=1,batch_size=128)


test_loss , test_acc = network.evaluate(test_images,test_labels)
print('test_acc:',test_acc)



network.save('m_lenet.h5')


#########

import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

model = load_model('/content/m_lenet.h5')

picPath = '/content/00_a.png'
img = Image.open(picPath)

# I though I resize here already
reIm = img.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)

im_arr = np.array(reIm.convert("L"))

import torch
import tensorflow as tf

# either input (im_arr) or (reIm) or (img), but they all get some error
tensor = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(im_arr)
im1 = tensor.reshape((1,28*28))
im1 = img.astype('float32')/255

predict = model.predict_classes(im1)
print ('predict as：')
print (predict)
```

---

tried code from export suggestion:

> array = np.array(im)

I screenshot result here https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNXmR.jpg

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
from PIL import Image


(train_images,train_labels),(test_images,test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images.shape
len(train_labels)
train_labels
test_images.shape
len(test_labels)
test_labels


'''plt.imshow(train_images[819], cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
print(train_images[819])
print(train_labels[819])'''


from keras import models
from keras import layers
network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512,activation='relu',input_shape=(28*28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))


network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


train_images = train_images.reshape((60000,28*28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32')/255
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000,28*28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')/255

from keras.utils import to_categorical

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

network.fit(train_images,train_labels,epochs=1,batch_size=128)


test_loss , test_acc = network.evaluate(test_images,test_labels)
print('test_acc:',test_acc)



network.save('m_lenet.h5')


#########

import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

model = load_model('/content/m_lenet.h5')

picPath = '/content/00_a.png'
img = Image.open(picPath)


reIm = img.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)


# add tried code 
im_arr = np.array(reIm)

import torch
import tensorflow as tf


tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(im_arr)
im1 = tensor.reshape((1,28*28))
im1 = img.astype('float32')/255

predict = model.predict_classes(im1)
print ('predict as：')
print (predict)
```

- output:

```
469/469 [==============================] - 7s 13ms/step - loss: 0.2557 - accuracy: 0.9263
313/313 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1256 - accuracy: 0.9627
test_acc: 0.9627000093460083
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d999f75eebea> in <module>
     77 
     78 tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(im_arr)
---> 79 im1 = tensor.reshape((1,28*28))
     80 im1 = img.astype('float32')/255
     81 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    443         from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
    444         np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
--> 445       """)
    446     self.__getattribute__(name)
    447 

AttributeError: EagerTensor object has no attribute 'reshape'. 
        If you are looking for numpy-related methods, please run the following:
        from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
        np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
```

Comment: Make sure you are providing the full path to the image `00_a.png`. plt.imshow() requires the input to be in float type, but your path which contains Chinese characters may cause that error. In short, try renaming your path to English.

Comment: hi @bit_scientist, thanks for ur advice, my path is `/content/00_a.png` , I make sure there get no chinese. That how to deal with `TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not due to path. When you are reading an image (like Png) with PIL, the type in `PngImageFile` which does not have reshape method. The reshape is for the tensor class. convert the Image that you read into proper data format you expect then rehsape and give to your model

```
tensor = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(im)
```

or

```
array = np.array(im)
...
```

and by the way looking at the error you printed, the image size could not be reshaped to the size you are interested, first you should resize then convert to tensor , array , etc and reshape.

Comment: I just tried ur suggestion, and put the result in post

Comment: I updated the post, but the error you printed is pretty informative. also I see that your image is of size size=273x367 , which means first you should resize to target size 28x28 then convert to tensor. however the step to convert to array or tensor should be as follow updated on post

Comment: I though I already resize by `reshape (28x28)` and `reIm = img.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)` and I also put tried code on post, pls take a look

Comment: the error was giving you information what you should do, you have a EdgeTensor which has no reshape method,